# Runtime Exception running robolectric tests IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robolectric

When running my robolectric tests in IntelliJ I get:

```
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowGeoPoint
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowItemizedOverlay
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowMapController
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowMapActivity
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowMapView
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowOverlayItem
WARNING: Unable to find path to Android SDK

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.init(ResourceLoader.java:158)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.setLayoutQualifierSearchPath(ResourceLoader.java:599)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setupApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:367)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.internalBeforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:311)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:278)
    at ...
```

The ANDROID_HOME ist set but InteliJ does not seem to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `sdk.dir` in a `local.properties` file by running the following in your project’s root dir:

```
$ android update project -p .
```

Setting up a `local.properties` file is a solution that will work for most IDEs since you don’t need to worry about getting environment variables passed around.

I got this from [`Unable to find Android SDK`](http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/resources.html#unable_to_find_android_sdk). There are also few other options which you may try.

Comment: @Torsten, would you mind accepting my answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Run Configurations (Run -> EditConfigurations..)
- Select your test from the left hand side (under JUnit)
- In the configurations tab, go to Environment Variables section and add an environment variable ANDROID_HOME pointing to your sdk
- Apply, build and run the test again

Note : You can add this in the JUnit default settings, so that you don't have to do for each test class